# Why do my derived classes only get Syntax Identifier Errors in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, syntax-error, derived-class

I am currently working on a simple face recognition project for school. A part of the architecture looks like this:

[image: Software architecture]

The Image class describes the width and height of the image. The RGBImage and IntensityImage (black and white) classes describe a few virtual methods for setting and getting pixels. The RGBImage**Private** and IntensityImage**Private** classes are already complete implementations of those virtual methods, they are inaccessible to us and are only used as an example. It is up to me to create my own version of the implementations in RGBImage**Student** and IntensityImage**Student**.

Now that is fun and all, but I'm currently getting about 25 "Syntax error: identifier" errors. (Which also are the only errors I'm getting.) I've been tweaking for a couple hours but I really can't figure it out.

Could you guys please help me figure this out?

**Image.h**

```
#pragma once
class Image {
private:
    int width;
    int height;

public:
    Image();
    Image(const int width, const int height);
    virtual ~Image();

    virtual void set(const int width, const int height);

    const int getWidth() const;
    const int getHeight() const;
};
```

**RGBImage.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Image.h"
#include "PixelType.h"

class RGBImage: public Image {
public:
    RGBImage();
    RGBImage(const int width, const int height);
    virtual ~RGBImage();

    virtual void set(const int width, const int height) = 0;

    virtual void setPixel(int x, int y, RGB pixel) = 0;
    virtual void setPixel(int i, RGB pixel) = 0;

    virtual RGB getPixel(int x, int y) const = 0;
    virtual RGB getPixel(int i) const = 0;

    virtual RGBImage* getRGB(IntensityImage *in) const {
        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

**RGBImageStudent.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "RGBImage.h"
#include "IntensityImageStudent.h"

class RGBImageStudent : public RGBImage {
public:
    RGB* _image;

    RGBImageStudent();
    RGBImageStudent(const RGBImageStudent &other);
    RGBImageStudent(const int width, const int height);
    ~RGBImageStudent();

    void set(const int width, const int height);
    void set(const RGBImageStudent &other);

    void setPixel(int x, int y, RGB pixel);
    void setPixel(int i, RGB pixel);

    RGB getPixel(int x, int y) const;
    RGB getPixel(int i) const;

    RGBImage* getRGB(IntensityImageStudent *in) const;
};
```

**RGBImageStudent.cpp**

```
#include "IntensityImageStudent.h"

IntensityImageStudent::IntensityImageStudent() : IntensityImage() {
}

IntensityImageStudent::IntensityImageStudent(const IntensityImageStudent &other) :
    IntensityImage(other.getWidth(), other.getHeight()),
    _image(new Intensity[other.getWidth() * other.getHeight()]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < getWidth() * getHeight(); ++i)
        _image[i] = other._image[i];
}

IntensityImageStudent::IntensityImageStudent(const int width, const int height) :
    IntensityImage(width, height),
    _image(new Intensity[width * height]) {
}

IntensityImageStudent::~IntensityImageStudent() {
    delete[] _image;
}

void IntensityImageStudent::set(const int width, const int height) {
    IntensityImage::set(width, height);
    delete[] _image;
    _image = new Intensity[width * height];
}

void IntensityImageStudent::set(const IntensityImageStudent &other) {
    IntensityImage::set(other.getWidth(), other.getHeight());
    if ((other.getWidth() * other.getHeight()) > (getWidth() * getHeight()))
        set(other.getWidth(), other.getHeight());
    else {
        delete[] _image;
        _image = new Intensity[getWidth() * getHeight()];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < getWidth() * getHeight(); ++i)
        _image[i] = other._image[i];
}

void IntensityImageStudent::setPixel(int x, int y, Intensity pixel) {
    _image[x + (y * getWidth())] = pixel;
}

void IntensityImageStudent::setPixel(int i, Intensity pixel) {
    _image[i] = pixel;
}

Intensity IntensityImageStudent::getPixel(int x, int y) const {
    return _image[x + (y * getWidth())];
}

Intensity IntensityImageStudent::getPixel(int i) const {
    return _image[i];
}

IntensityImage* IntensityImageStudent::getIntensity(RGBImageStudent *in) const {
    IntensityImageStudent* out = new IntensityImageStudent(in->getWidth(), in->getHeight());

    for (int i = 0; i < (getWidth() * getHeight()); ++i)
        out->_image[i] = Intensity(0.2126 * in->_image[i].r + 0.7152 * in->_image[i].g + 0.0722 * in->_image[i].b);

    return out;
}
```

**All these errors are thrown on the getRGB() and getIntensity() methods, but only in the header files.**

> Error 13 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IntensityImageStudent' rgbimagestudent.h
>
> Error 18 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'RGBImageStudent' intensityimagestudent.h
>
> Error 24 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'RGBImage' intensityimage.h
>
> Error 25 error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IntensityImage' rgbimage.h

Comment: Far too much code! Do you have a _minimal testcase_ for us?

Comment: And please copy the exact compiler's output. Regarding the IntensityImage error in rgbimage.h: you do not include intensityimage.h in rgbimage.h.

Answer (score 0):

The identifier error is telling you that the compiler doesn't know what a given identifier is. Taking one of the ones in your example:

```
virtual RGBImage* getRGB(IntensityImage *in) const {
```

The compiler doesn't know what `IntensityImage` is. You don't `#include` any header that defines it, there's no typedef, etc. So it can't process that method declaration. You need to provide a declaration for these types.

Comment: Hey Barry, thank you for your quick reply! I have added the `#include IntensityImage.h` , unfortunately it still gives the syntax errors. I will try to find another way around this problem by adding an extra class.